# Seeking news about Lunar Tunnel Boring Machine (TBM)

Tags: construction, lunar-base

My last question was a bit to specific.  Does anyone have any news about lunar tunnel boring machines?

Reference to last question
[Can anyone find a more recent NASA paid for study on lunar tunnel-boring machine?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/34678/can-anyone-find-a-more-recent-nasa-paid-for-study-on-lunar-tunnel-boring-machine)

Comment: Better edit that question instead of making a new one...